# Method 'Range' of object '_Application' failed

Tags: excel, runtime-error, vba

I'm making a user form named 'fmtToolBar' but any attempt at runninig the code fails with:

Run-time error '1004':
Method 'Range' of object '_Application' failed

> > Sub ToolbarShow()
> > Dim form As fmtToolBar
> > Set form = fmtToolBar
> > form.Show (0)    'This is to make the form modeless so that you can work with the excel spreadsheet with the form open'

End Sub

I've also tried using

> > fmtToolBar.Show vbModeless
> > Application.Range("DrawMap").Value = True 'Draw map is a cell name in the excel file'

this also causes the same error.

---

## Solved

I found the error in that the program would remove all names from the cells so it couldn't find the cell "DrawMap" because it kept getting renamed to the default.

Comment: When is the error raised? On which line? I suspect that error is related to your Defined name. I duplicated your code and had no issues.

Answer (score -1):

Just click on the form in the VBA editor and in the properties menu set the `ShowModal` value to false.

Comment: How does this answer the OP's question?

Comment: Perhaps, but it likely won't solve the error the OP is seeing, which is the point of the question.

Comment: It is set to false. Anyway I fixed it, stepping through the program, it kept resetting the names of the cells so the macro couldn't find the proper cell

Comment: @Stephen sounds like there was much more to this code than was originally posted, I would suggest you post a much bigger portion (if not all) of your code next time. The bit we can see now simply shows that you are trying to make the form modal and address 1 value on a sheet